# Class Declaration - Custom Error Messages

Tags: javascript, class, oop

I am trying to create a custom Class in JS in which I have to limit the arguments passed to the Class. Basically, I want to create a Class where it throws an error unless the argument passed to the Class is 'foo', 'bar', or 'foobar'. I've have tried reading the documentation, but being new to JavaScript, but being brand new to JS, I can't make heads or tails of it.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be easy enough to put a check in your `class` `constructor` method that includes a condition to throw an error if the class requirements are not adhered to:

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor(arg) {
    const acceptableArgs = ['foo', 'bar', 'foobar'];
    if (!acceptableArgs.includes(arg)) {
      throw new Error('MyClass instance must be declared with "foo", "bar", or "foobar"!');
    }
    this.arg = arg;
  }
  sayHello() {
    console.log(`Hi my arg is ${this.arg}`);
  }
}

const works = new MyClass('foo');
works.sayHello();

const doesnotwork = new MyClass('uhoh');
doesnotwork.sayHello();
```

Comment: No problem, and welcome to the site.  If you have any questions on asking questions you can always review [ask].  If this answer was satisfactory, please mark it as "accepted" so that other users that find this post know that this approach is likely to work for them as well.  Good luck, and happy coding!